# os.platform() Not Working Correctly In Website

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, operating-system

I'm using the built-in 'os.platform()' function in Node.js to get the home directory of a user when they sign in to a website so they can import files. In order to specify which path to look for those files in, I need to know the OS of the user's PC. When I run the code in my local server, it runs fine, returning "win32". However, when I deploy the website, it always reads "linux", which I can only assume is the operating system of the server. How can I make sure that "os.platform()" returns the client's OS and nothing else?

I should also mention that I am running this code with a `console.log(os.platform())` in `getInitialProps()`. I've tried using navigator, window, and process.env.HOME but none of those have worked for me, as they always return undefined inside of getInitialProps().